# Sorting a String Array using a Comparator based on a Character in the String

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, comparator

So I'm trying to sort a String Array using a Comparator but the sorting is based on the length of String then on the third Character of the String.

This is my Comparator so far:

```
class StringSorter implements Comparator<String> {
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        if(s1.length() < s2.length()) {
            return -1;
        }
        if(s1.length() > s2.length()) {
            return 1;
        }    
        return s1.charAt(3)+"".compareTo(s2.charAt(3)+"");
    }
}//Comparator
```

This line `return s1.charAt(3)+"".compareTo(s2.charAt(3)+"");` is my attempt so far and I get an IndexOutOfBoundsException but every String in my Array has at least the length of 4 so I don't understand why the error.

As for my question, why do I get that error? and is that how I should write my Comparator if I'm to sort based on length and a character in the String?

Edit: The Arrays I need to process follows this format

```
{"1:bbbbb", "2:aaa", "=:ccc", "1:qqqq", "1:eeee", "=:zzz", "1:vvv", "2:oooo", "=:eee", "1:fffff"}
```

Comment: you question needs to be verifiable, so please provide sample inputs

Comment: Include the arrays you're testing with

Comment: "but every String in my Array has at least the length of 4 so I don't understand why the error." It is wrong as otherwise you would not have the exception. Set a breakpoint and run in debug mode or other way : add a check and throw an exception if the String length is superior to 4.

Comment: Observation : does `compareTo` get called on `""` or on `s1.charAt(3)+""`? Interesting order precedence thing here, maybe.

Comment: @KarlReid is probably right, I would assume `charAt` is being called on an empty string. That would fully explain your error.

Comment: Note that your code could be simplified (and made correct, and made clearer, and made faster) to `Comparator<String> c = Comparator.comparingInt(String::length).thenComparingInt(s -> s.charAt(3));`.

Comment: @alirabiee, Sorry for that, I've added one now.

Comment: @davidxxx I did say at least, so each String length wont go below 4.

Comment: @KarlReid, I'll check on that.

Comment: @KarlReid, I've replaced both with this `Character.toString(s1.charAt(3)).compareTo(Character.toString(s2.charAt(3)))` and same error shows.

Comment: No need to do all to convert to string etc. Just use- new Character(s1.charAt(2)).compareTo(s2.charAt(2))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine. I've tweaked it a bit here to show you how you can make it more resilient though.

```
class StringSorter implements Comparator<String> {
    private final int pos;

    public StringSorter(int pos) {
        this.pos = pos;
    }

    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        if (s1.length() < s2.length()) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (s1.length() > s2.length()) {
            return 1;
        }
        if ( s1.length() <= pos ) {
            return s1.compareTo(s2);
        }
        return Character.compare(s1.charAt(pos),s2.charAt(pos));
    }
}

public void test() {
    String[] test2 = {"1:bbbbb", "2:aaa", "=:ccc", "1:qqqq", "1:eeee", "=:zzz", "1:vvv", "2:oooo", "=:eee", "1:fffff"};
    System.out.println("Before: " + Arrays.toString(test2));
    Arrays.sort(test2, new StringSorter (2));
    System.out.println("After:  " + Arrays.toString(test2));
}
```

prints:

> Before: [1:bbbbb, 2:aaa, =:ccc, 1:qqqq, 1:eeee, =:zzz, 1:vvv, 2:oooo, =:eee, 1:fffff]
>
> After:  [2:aaa, =:ccc, =:eee, 1:vvv, =:zzz, 1:eeee, 2:oooo, 1:qqqq, 1:bbbbb, 1:fffff]

I suspect you are using `3` meaning the 3rd character - this is wrong. The `3rd` character is at position `2`;

**Remember - the nth character in a String is indexed by [n-1] because the first is at `0`**.

Answer (score 1):

This is solution for your problem using ternary operator.

Simple one liner comparison method.

```
class StringSorter implements Comparator<String> {

    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return s1.length() - s2.length() != 0 ? s1.length() - s2.length() :  new Character(s1.charAt(2)).compareTo(s2.charAt(2));
    }
}
```